# Boolean doesn't work

Tags: modifiers

So i am new to blender and when i want to use the boolean modifier nothing happens.
The boolean modifier also worked before.
[Here is my Blender file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/fpz912bzido0zqf/katana1.blend/file).

Comment: Objects used for Boolean to Difference have Normals in a wrong direction (inward). You can see that when enabled Face orientation in overlays. In edit mode switch normals outward (Shift+N) ... or use Fast Solver instead Exact ... but what I saw you would have to remodel

Comment: Oh, of course, that too. Then he won't have to use "Fast" instead of "Exact", but there are other occasions where "Exact" also doesn't work as expected (at least in some previous Blender versions) so it's not wrong to try it with "Fast".

Answer (score 2):

At first, you have set the *Boolean Modifier* to *Operand Type* "Object", this way you can only specify a single object, but you have a collection of objects. Switch *Object Type* to "Collection" and select the "boolean" collection.

Then the *Solver* option is set to "Exact". Although exact sounds better, "Fast" usually gives more correct results (don't ask me why, maybe "Exact" isn't properly working).

And afterwards you might want to disable visibility of the "boolean" collection, or else the objects will be obstructing your view on the result.

By the way, you could use the *Operand Type* "Object" as well, but then you need all your objects merged into one or a *Boolean Modifier* for each object on its own.

EDIT: As others here pointed out, recalculating the normals would help, too - in this case even "Exact" would work.

Comment: You might want to enable the "Auto Smooth" option under _Object Data Properties_ > _Normals_ as well as it makes the smoothed surface look better after the bool.

Comment: Exact has problems with self intersecting geometry. Use the 3D Printing plugin to find these problems.

Comment: @Gunslinger I guess in this case it's the flipped normals which "Exact" didn't like, there was no self-intersecting geometry.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, thanks. I use booleans a lot and am always eager to get them to work better. Also, before and after boolean I always use "Make manifold".

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to Blender, here the "extended directors cut" of vklidus comment:

Klick on that little caret right of the two circles and it will open the viewport overlays dialog.

Check the "face orientation" checkbox.

[image]

In the viewport you will see now only blue and red colors.

Blue means good -> the face is facing outwards.
Red means evil -> the face is facing inwards.

Normally red is wrong, but of course, there are case where red is right. e.g. if you move with the camera inside a cube, of course the faces inside the cube will be red then (if the cube does not have a solidify modifier...).

So you can see that the sword has some red faces.

To fix this, select the sword, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and then <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices and then click on Mesh -> Normals -> recalculate normals.

[image]

you will notice, that some red faces will turn to blue.

Repeat this for all red faces.

After that the boolean should work.

by the way, it is always a good idea to change the "viewport display" -> "display as" of the cutter to "bounds" so that you can see what the result of the boolean operation is.

[image]

Comment: Actually, although I overlooked the fact that the normals are wrong, setting the modifier to "Fast" instead of "Exact" will ignore this flaw. But then still it won't work as he wants because he set the Operand Type wrong. Or at least it will only work on one object, but I guess he wants all of those in the collection ;)